# Convert rows values of FieldName and TableName to ClassName and its properties and save to DB using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have a table `Sync_Transaction` which has a column `FieldName` which stores column names of another table `DDR_Transaction` and `NewValues` which are values I want to insert/update.

Now I want build className from TableName and properties of that class from FieldName and insert into table using Entity Framework.

Sync_Transaction

```
RecordId    DMLType TableName   PKId    FieldName   OldValue    NewValue
1   I   DDR_Transaction 1   DDRId   NULL    1
2   I   DDR_Transaction 1   VesselID    NULL    31
3   I   DDR_Transaction 1   TransactionID   NULL    0
4   I   DDR_Transaction 1   GeneratedDate   NULL    Aug  1 2019 12:07PM
5   I   DDR_Transaction 1   MasterName  NULL    Master Name
6   I   DDR_Transaction 1   ChiefEngineerName   NULL    Chief Engineer Name
7   I   DDR_Transaction 1   Title   NULL    FIRST DDR
8   I   DDR_Transaction 1   ComponentNo NULL    13463
9   I   DDR_Transaction 1   TypeOfDefect    NULL    NON-ESSENTIAL
10  I   DDR_Transaction 1   Severity    NULL    1
11  I   DDR_Transaction 1   VIQChapterId    NULL    1
12  I   DDR_Transaction 1   VIQRefId    NULL    1
13  I   DDR_Transaction 1   Responsibility  NULL    6
14  I   DDR_Transaction 1   IdentifiedDate  NULL    Jul 28 2019 12:00AM
15  I   DDR_Transaction 1   RepairedBy  NULL    1
16  I   DDR_Transaction 1   PlannedFor  NULL    4
17  I   DDR_Transaction 1   Priority    NULL    9
18  I   DDR_Transaction 1   DueDate NULL    Aug 10 2019 12:00AM
19  I   DDR_Transaction 1   EstStartDate    NULL    Aug  3 2019 12:00AM
20  I   DDR_Transaction 1   EstCompletionDate   NULL    Aug  5 2019 12:00AM
21  I   DDR_Transaction 1   IsSMSRequired   NULL    0
22  I   DDR_Transaction 1   IsRARequired    NULL    0
23  I   DDR_Transaction 1   IsMOCRequired   NULL    0
24  I   DDR_Transaction 1   IsPTWRequired   NULL    0
25  I   DDR_Transaction 1   IsReliability   NULL    0
26  I   DDR_Transaction 1   DescOfDefectDamage  NULL    TEST FIRST
27  I   DDR_Transaction 1   CauseOfDamage   NULL    TEST FIRST CAUSE
28  I   DDR_Transaction 1   IsJobCardAmended    NULL    0
29  I   DDR_Transaction 1   IsAdditionalJobs    NULL    0
30  I   DDR_Transaction 1   ISDraft NULL    0
31  I   DDR_Transaction 1   CreatedBy   NULL    17
32  I   DDR_Transaction 1   CreatedDate NULL    Aug  1 2019 12:07PM
33  I   DDR_Transaction 1   IsDeleted   NULL    0
34  U   DDR_Transaction 1   GeneratedDate   Aug  1 2019 12:07PM Aug  1 2019 12:07PM
35  U   DDR_Transaction 1   ComponentNo 13463   13409
36  U   DDR_Transaction 1   DescOfRepairPlanned NULL    repiared
37  U   DDR_Transaction 1   IsJobCardAmended    0   1
38  U   DDR_Transaction 1   IsAdditionalJobs    0   1
39  U   DDR_Transaction 1   RepairDate  NULL    Aug 14 2019 12:00AM
40  U   DDR_Transaction 1   CreatedDate Aug  1 2019 12:07PM Aug  1 2019 12:07PM
41  U   DDR_Transaction 1   ModifiedBy  NULL    17
42  U   DDR_Transaction 1   ModifiedDate    NULL    Aug  1 2019 12:09PM
```

DDR_Transaction

```
DDRId   int
VesselID    int
TransactionID   int
DDRNo   varchar
GeneratedDate   datetime
MasterName  nvarchar
ChiefEngineerName   nvarchar
Title   nvarchar
ComponentNo int
TypeOfDefect    nvarchar
Severity    int
VIQChapterId    int
VIQRefId    int
Responsibility  int
IdentifiedDate  datetime
RepairedBy  nvarchar
PlannedFor  nvarchar
Priority    nvarchar
DueDate datetime
EstStartDate    datetime
EstCompletionDate   datetime
IsSMSRequired   bit
IsRARequired    bit
IsMOCRequired   bit
IsPTWRequired   bit
SMSTransID  int
RATransID   int
MOCTransID  int
PTWTransID  int
DockPlanJobNo   int
IsReliability   bit
ReliabilityType int
OffHireTimeInMinutes    int
OffHireTimeInHours  decimal
Comments    nvarchar
DescOfDefectDamage  nvarchar
CauseOfDamage   nvarchar
DescOfRepairPlanned nvarchar
IsJobCardAmended    bit
PMSChangeRequestTransID int
IsAdditionalJobs    bit
RepairDate  datetime
ISDraft bit
CreatedBy   int
CreatedDate datetime
ModifiedBy  int
ModifiedDate    datetime
IsDeleted   bit
DeletedBy   int
DeletedDate datetime
```

Comment: This is not something you should be using EF to do since the metadata about your db model is stored in another db table.

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, You cannot create a class and use it to map model using EF at run time for 2 main reasons:

1. Entity must be set in a `DbSet` if you mapping directly or must
   Implement `IEntityTypeConfiguration` if you are explicitly mapping
   entities
2. Considering `DesignTimeDbContextFactory` Run for your application
   where it runs your mapping and chekcs for your connection and
   migrations etc so its quite impossible to do what you have mentioned
   with Entity Framework.

I recommend you using a `trigger` on your reference table, sort of **each time data is updated**, you run a stored procedure that reads the values from it and modifies the target table structure such as needed.

You can call that stored procedure from code with Entity Framework aswell.

Hope it helps,

Comment: This could be a way.. I will try using Stored procedure... Thanks for help